# How to get urllib2 response in json

Tags: python, json

I have the following code:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
```

What would be the most straightforward way to get this in `json` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of "http://python.org/" is not returning json documents.

You can check the types of your output as below:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
>>> response.headers.type
'text/html'
>>>
```

OK, lets see one example of json response api:

```
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random')
>>> response.headers.type
'application/json'
>>>
```

So, here in the header type you can see the 'application/json' which means that the reponse contain json documents.

```
>>> import json
>>> json_docs = json.load(response)
>>> print json_docs
{u'type': u'success', u'value': {u'joke': u'How many Chuck Norris require to screw a light     bulb? None, he will screw it all.', u'id': 562, u'categories': []}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a response object, you would do

```
jsondata = json.load(response)
```

Of course, you will be fetching data from a URL that is actually JSON data (`http://python.org/` is not JSON).